How to change variable/dynamic json content
This is how I modify a tsconfig.json file in a python script. But as you can see, the most part is quite the same, so this is not a very elegant solution.
As I'm new to python, I need some help how to write this code more efficient.
And also there is another if case where I have to add a single parameter (e.g. "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": False) or set an existing one to different value (False).
with open('/'.join([directory, "tsconfig.json"]),'r+') as file:
    file_data = json.load(file)
    if plugin == "node":
        file_data["compilerOptions"] = {
            "module": "commonjs",
            "strict": True,
            "alwaysStrict": True,
            "noImplicitAny": True,
            "noImplicitThis": True,
            "strictNullChecks": True,
            "strictBindCallApply": True,
            "strictFunctionTypes": True,
            "strictPropertyInitialization": True,
            "useUnknownInCatchVariables": True,
            "noUnusedLocals": True,
            "noUnusedParameters": True,
            "allowUnusedLabels": True,
            "allowUnreachableCode": True,
            "noImplicitOverride": True,
            "noImplicitReturns": True,
            "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": True,
            "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": True,
            "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": True,
            "exactOptionalPropertyTypes": True,
            "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": True
        }
    elif plugin == 'react':
        file_data["compilerOptions"] = {
            "jsx": "react-jsx",
            "allowJs": False,
            "esModuleInterop": False,
            "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": True,
            "strict": True,
            "alwaysStrict": True,
            "noImplicitAny": True,
            "noImplicitThis": True,
            "strictNullChecks": True,
            "strictBindCallApply": True,
            "strictFunctionTypes": True,
            "strictPropertyInitialization": True,
            "useUnknownInCatchVariables": True,
            "noUnusedLocals": True,
            "noUnusedParameters": True,
            "allowUnusedLabels": True,
            "allowUnreachableCode": True,
            "noImplicitOverride": True,
            "noImplicitReturns": True,
            "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": True,
            "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": True,
            "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": True,
            "exactOptionalPropertyTypes": True,
            "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": True
        }
    file.seek(0)
    json.dump(file_data, file, indent = 2)


You can create and assign a dict with the common items and then something like file_data["compilerOptions"].update({"jsx": "react-jsx", "allowJs": False}) to add or change specific items.

For a single parameter (add or change): file_data["compilerOptions"]["noUncheckedIndexedAccess"] = False

You should work out what's common and what's unique. Then you can have three "static" dictionaries - one for the common data, one for the data that's unique to "react" and another that's unique to "node".
Also, note that when rewriting a file that's been opened in r+ mode you should make sure to call truncate() unless you're absolutely certain that the file can only ever increase in size. Even if the size does increase, calling truncate() will be benign and is therefore best practice.
import json

COMMON = {
    "strict": True,
    "alwaysStrict": True,
    "noImplicitAny": True,
    "noImplicitThis": True,
    "strictNullChecks": True,
    "strictBindCallApply": True,
    "strictFunctionTypes": True,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": True,
    "useUnknownInCatchVariables": True,
    "noUnusedLocals": True,
    "noUnusedParameters": True,
    "allowUnusedLabels": True,
    "allowUnreachableCode": True,
    "noImplicitOverride": True,
    "noImplicitReturns": True,
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": True,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": True,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": True,
    "exactOptionalPropertyTypes": True,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": True,
}

NODE = {"module": "commonjs"}

REACT = {
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "allowJs": False,
    "esModuleInterop": False,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": True,
}


def update(filename, plugin):
    with open(filename, "r+") as file:
        data = json.load(file)
        data["compilerOptions"] = COMMON
        match plugin:
            case "node":
                data["compilerOptions"].update(NODE)
            case "react":
                data["compilerOptions"].update(REACT)
            case _:
                pass
        file.seek(0)
        json.dump(data, file, indent=4)
        file.truncate()


update("tsconfig.json", "node")

